# The menu disappear on resize when click on menu toggle

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, responsive-design

When I click on menu toggle and resize browser window, the menu will disappear.
[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/65kjz3ej/)

This is the jQuery for menu:

```
$('.menu ul li ul').parent().addClass('parent');

$(".menu-toggle").click(function() {

  $("#nav").slideToggle(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded");
  });

});
```

On mobile, I want to deactivate the hover effects and replace it with the toggle effect for the sub child's menu via jQuery; how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to css: updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65kjz3ej/2/)

```
.menu #nav {
display : block;    

}
```

`EDIT:`

what if instead of slidetoggle we use left : 0 and left: 100%, will it satisfy requirement?  check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65kjz3ej/3/)

Comment: No, firstly resize browser window smaller and click on menu toggle twice and resize again bigger and see what's happen, the menu is will disappear.

Comment: @Uikithemes : please check the edit in answer and tell me if this helps.

Comment: Yes is working fine but I don't want the slide from righ to left, I want the toggle effect? so how? and thank you very much for your help.